# Polymorphic subscriptions in NServiceBus works only for interfaces?

Tags: nservicebus

The simplest way to follow this explanation is a NServiceBus Pub/Sub sample which contains example of "polymorphic subscriptions" (Subscriber2).

**Messages:** (without changes)

```
public class EventMessage : IEvent
{
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Time { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
}

public interface IEvent : IMessage
{
    Guid EventId { get; set; }
    DateTime? Time { get; set; }
    TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
}
```

**Handler:** (without changes)

```
public class EventMessageHandler : IHandleMessages<IEvent>
{
    public void Handle(IEvent message)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This handler will receive both `IEvent` and `EventMessage` messages. But if I will make IEvent a class...

```
public class IEvent : IMessage
{
    Guid EventId { get; set; }
    DateTime? Time { get; set; }
    TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
}
```

...then **i will not be able to receive** `EventMessage` but will receive `IEvent` as before

So i found such simple rule: if you use interface in IHandleMessages<> - it will work, if class - it will not work. Currently i have all messages as classes and i would like to subscribe to parent class message in order to receive all child class messages.

Is it intended behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all by design in order to enable multiple inheritance.  The reasons to do so are detailed [here](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/messages-as-interfaces).  Publicly available events between Business Components are recommended to be modeled as interfaces, commands within a business component are recommended to be modeled as classes.  Sounds like you want this behaviour, I would switch over to interfaces.